# Form complaining about a missing component not used in that form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer

I wrote a small Winforms application in C# .Net 3.5 using VS2012.

Form X launch an external console application used to fill a table in a SQL Server 2012 database; Form Y uses a `ReportViewer` control to load and show a `RDLC` report from the table.

`ReportViewer` has to be installed in the client computer. If `ReportViewer` is missing, of course Form Y reports an error of `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms` missing.

Why does Form X report the same error when the user clicks the button that launches the external console application, and in that moment only?

In that form, nor in the external application, nor in the button click event, there is nothing related to `ReportViewer`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Just look at the call stack.